# The import com.projectname.R cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

Problem is the following error message:

```
The import com.projectname.R cannot be resolved.
```

When I add my classes

```
import android.R
```

`R can not be resolved' problem  gone but another problem occur.

Another problem as well with `R.id.id1`

```
id1 cannot be resolved or is not a field.
```

I use eclipse Adt.

Any idea how I can solve the error? How can I handle the import?

Comment: try file -> invalidate caches / restart

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using Android Studio.

Try to do Build > Clean Project and then Build > Rebuild Project.